# Are new connections the only data i should expect from a server FD when checking for things to read with epoll

Tags: c++, sockets, epoll

I have a server file descriptor that is watched (pardon me if it is the wrong term) by epoll.
In my main loop, I iterate over the file descriptors that are ready to read. If my program sees the server file descriptor, it blindly issues the `accept()` syscall. I get a feeling that I am in the process of making a mistake. Is `accept()` the only handling that the "listening" file descriptor will do? Or are there other things that are being ignored by me here?

My event loop is like this:

```cpp
  while (true){
        event_count = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, MAX_EVENTS, 300);
        for (int i=0; i < event_count; i ++){
            if (events[i].data.fd == sockfd){
                int newsock = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr,  
                       (socklen_t*)&addr_len);
                struct epoll_event event_c; 
                event_c.events = EPOLLIN;
                event_c.data.fd = newsock;
                std::cout << "Added client" << std::endl;
                epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, newsock, &event_c);
            }
            else {
                // handle other things to read here
            }
    }
```

Comment: No mistake, that's all it can do when readable.

Comment: You did set the socket non-blocking, right? Otherwise, the `accept` call can block if the incoming connection was aborted by the other side. You also need to check the return value from `accept`!

Comment: > You did set the socket non-blocking, right?
No, I did not. I was not sure if it was appropriate.
> You also need to check the return value from `accept`
Yes, I should be checking it. I now am, Thanks